# Renaming parametrized tests in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Parametrized tests in Pytest have the following id format:
`<function name>[<param identifier>]`.

I would like to be able to totally control the name of the Test Case when these are parametrized.

For example, I currently have the following code:

```py
import pytest

list_args = ["a", "b", "c"]


@pytest.fixture(params=list_args)
def prog_arg(request):
    yield request.param


def test_001():
    # This should not be changed
    pass

def test_002(prog_arg):
    # This should be test_002_01, test_002_02, ...
    print(prog_arg)


ids = [f"test_003_{i+1:02d}" for i in range(len(list_args))]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg", list_args, ids=ids)
def test_003(arg):
    # This should be test_003_01, test_003_02, ...
    print(prog_arg)
```

When I run (**pytest 5.1.3**), I have:

```
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_001 PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_002[a] PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_002[b] PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_002[c] PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_003[test_003_01] PASSED                                                                                                                                                   
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_003[test_003_02] PASSED                                                                                                                                                  
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_003[test_003_03] PASSED
```

What I would like is to have:

```
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_001 PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_002_01 PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_002_02 PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_002_03 PASSED
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_003_01 PASSED                                                                                                                                                   
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_003_02 PASSED                                                                                                                                                  
test_rename_id.py::test_TC_003_03 PASSED
```

Is it possible without too much hacking of the request `object` (or other modifications that might got broken in future updates of `pytest`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surely possible by rewriting the `nodeid`s of the collected items. In the example below, I rewrite `nodeid`s in a custom impl of the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook. Place the following code into your `conftest.py`:

```
# conftest.py

import itertools as it
import re


def grouper(item):
    return item.nodeid[:item.nodeid.rfind('[')]


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for _, group in it.groupby(items, grouper):
        for i, item in enumerate(group):
            item._nodeid = re.sub(r'\[.*\]', '_{:02d}'.format(i + 1), item.nodeid)
```

Running your test module from the question now yields:

```
test_spam.py::test_001 PASSED
test_spam.py::test_002_01 PASSED
test_spam.py::test_002_02 PASSED
test_spam.py::test_002_03 PASSED
test_spam.py::test_003_01 PASSED
test_spam.py::test_003_02 PASSED
test_spam.py::test_003_03 PASSED
```

Comment: So beautifully powerful. Thanks for sharing and solving this issue. A minor improvement: adding a `$` in the replacement pattern: `item._nodeid = re.sub(r"\[.*?\]$", "_{:02d}".format(i + 1), item.nodeid)` and lazy pattern (`.*?`). Does it actually improve speed??

Comment: Glad I could help! You can play with and benchmark the different regular expressions, but TBH I don't think it will be any significant difference in performance here, most of the time will be spent in collecting the test functions from files anyways.

Comment: Making the greedy quantifier more specific will surely bring some minor speed, and avoiding the regex compilation in the loop by placing a `pattern = re.compile(...)` outside the loop will also be an improvement, but I wouldn't expect great performance gains from those.

Comment: yes indeed, not great performance gain... and anyway, it's not what will slow down the whole process. Your solution works like a charm by the way.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs available in the pytest, I would like to apprise you that the way **ids** work in the pytest.mark.paramterize is just like the output you mentioned in your question.

The format is:-
**filename-testname-idsvalue**.

Reference:- https://hackebrot.github.io/pytest-tricks/param_id_func/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input but this is not what I am looking for. (I have also came across this nice page when doing my research for solution). I have currently a format like `test_ids.py::test_foobar[1-b0]` but I would like something like `test_ids.py::test_foobar_01`.